# Range(Cell.Find("Price tag"), Range(Cells.Find("Price tag")).End(xlDown))

Tags: excel, vba, find, range, cell

I want to find where 'price tag' is on the sheet, and follow that column to select all way down.
I have wrote

Range(Cells.Find("Price tag"), Range(Cells.Find("Price Tag")).End(xlDown))

but I got [range method of object _global failed] message.
What is wrong with the code, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using the Find Method

- If the searched value is not found, the result will be `Nothing`, so it is safest to use a range variable with the `Find` method, and then test the variable against `Nothing`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim ColumnRange As Range

    Dim fCell As Range ' simplified due to assuming it is never in cell `A1`
    Set fCell = ws.Cells.Find("Price Tag", , xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByRows)
    
    ' Decide what to do if found or not.
    If fCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "'Price Tag' not found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set ColumnRange = ws.Range(fCell, fCell.End(xlDown))
        MsgBox "'Price Tag' was found in cell '" & fCell.Address(0, 0) _
            & "' and the address of your range is '" _
            & ColumnRange.Address(0, 0) & "'.", vbInformation
    End If
        
    ' But usually you know in which row...
    With ws.Rows(1)
        Set fCell = .Find("Price Tag", .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    End With
    
    ' or in which column it is:
    With ws.Columns("A")
        Set fCell = .Find("Price Tag", .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have One more question. You wrote a code that shows the address of the cell, but can I keep the cell Address in a variable so that I can use that information later in code?

Comment: The variable is alive until you exit the sub, so you can do whatever is possible with it. You can read its address, chane its value `fCell.Value = 5`, you can select 5 cells to the right `fCell.Offset(0, 5).Select`, resize it ...etc. Not sure what exactly you meant? I this didn't help, be more specific.

Comment: Thanks, you've got what I wanted! The only problem was that I couldn't fully understand the code. Thanks to your additional explain, I've got this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This function will extend the selections for you.

```
Public Function DataCells(Source As Range) As Range
    Dim ColUsedRange As Range
    Dim Col As Range
    Dim RowCount As Long
    
    For Each Col In Source.Columns
        Set ColUsedRange = Range(Col, Col.EntireColumn.Cells(Source.Parent.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If RowCount < ColUsedRange.Rows.Count Then RowCount = ColUsedRange.Rows.Count
    Next
    
    Set DataCells = Source.Resize(RowCount)
End Function
```

### Usage

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = Cells.Find("Price tag")
    
    If Not Target Is Nothing Then
        Set Target = DataCells(Target)
        Application.Goto Target
    End If
End Sub
```